# Nodemailer sends email but cant get response from it

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, async-await, nodemailer

am trying to send a email with nodemailer and its sending successfully but its not getting any response so that i can be shown to client side . here is the code

```
    let mailTransporter = nodemailer.createTransport({ 
        service: 'gmail', 
        auth: { 
            user: 'user123@gmail.com', //your email
            pass: ' ' //password
        }
       
      
    }); 
      
    let mailDetails = { 
        from: 'user123@gmail.com', 
        to: 'user125@gmail.com', 
        subject: 'mail', 
        text: 'Thanks for email'
    }; 
      
    mailTransporter.sendMail(mailDetails, function(err, data) { 
        if(err) { 
            console.log(err); 
        } 
        else { 
            res.status(200).send(data)
            console.log(data); 
        } 
    }); 
}
```

Comment: Can you try to put your code into async function

Comment: Do you see anything in the console for `console.log(err);` or `console.log(data);`? Also you should respond no matter if there was an error or not, in your case you only rerspond if there was no error.

Comment: @Molda, that's not the case... he won't get any error because email goes through but since he has not created async function, code execute successfully without response.

Comment: @Soheb There's no need for any async function `sendMail` function takes 2 parameters, First the message and second is a callback function with `err, info` which is called after the message was send. The callback function should be called in both.

Comment: @Molda, I am sorry you are right... I just read the docs and callback should give error or info